# Swift Webkit Webview with WebRTC produces a Black Video Screen

Tags: ios, swift, video, webrtc

I am having an issue that only occurs with Swift, Webkit abd WebRTC. I am creating a webview of this url:

https://widgets.bingewave.com/webrtc/6b8bcc00-864d-4c97-8e15-0b3aed37946b

The complete code is here: https://github.com/BingeWave/bingewave-swift-video-app

The code for creating the Webview is this:

**Webview**

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct SwiftUIWebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let url: URL?

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomWebView {
        //Preferences
        let prefs = WKWebpagePreferences()
        prefs.allowsContentJavaScript = true
        
        //Create a congif
        let config =  WKWebViewConfiguration()
        
        //Add
        config.defaultWebpagePreferences = prefs
        return CustomWebView(
            frame: .zero,
            configuration: config
        )
    }
        
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let myURL = url else {
            return
            
        }
        let request =  URLRequest (url: myURL)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
```

**CustomWebView.swift**

```
//
//  CustomWebView.swift
//  BingWave Sample App Swift
//
//  Created by Ayusma on 07/04/2022.
//
import WebKit


class CustomWebView: WKWebView {
    //Change th Auth Token with that of a user
    let AUTH_TOKEN = "xxxxxxx";
    
    override func load(_ request: URLRequest) -> WKNavigation? {
        guard let mutableRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = request as? NSMutableURLRequest else {
            return super.load(request)
        }
        mutableRequest.setValue(AUTH_TOKEN, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        return super.load(mutableRequest as URLRequest)
    }
}
```

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    let BINGWAVE_URL = URL(string:  "https://widgets.bingewave.com/webrtc/6b8bcc00-864d-4c97-8e15-0b3aed37946b")
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            SwiftUIWebView(url: BINGWAVE_URL)
                .navigationTitle("BingWave Sample App")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The issue is the screen loads the view, I am able to join the video chat but my camera video black and if another user joins, their video is a black within the app. What is weird is they can see me and themsevles on their end, so the video is only black on the iOS app. And this works for other implements like a React Native Webview, it only fails for this implementation with Swift.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Did you solve it bro, i have the same problem